# Existence and structure of a group of order $p^2q$ where $p\mid q-1$ from a given presentation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $p$ and $q$ be integer primes such that $p$ divides $q-1$.

(a) Show that there exists a group $G$ of order $p^{2}q$ with generators $x$ and $y$ such that $x^{p^{2}} =1$, $y^{q}=1$, and $xyx^{-1}=y^{a}$, with $1$ the identity element of $G$ and $a$ some integer such that $a\not\equiv 1 \pmod q$ but $a^{p}\equiv 1\pmod q$.

(b) Prove that Sylow $q$-subgroup $S_{q}$ is normal in $G$, $G/S_{q}$ is cyclic and deduce that $G$ has a unique subgroup $H$ of order $pq$.

Comment: Show your work? We are not here to give answers to your homework.

Comment: ok, I have just come back,I should say that this is not my homework. Actually this is to show the existence of the semidirect product of two cyclic group of order $p^{2} ,q$, since the Aut of the group of order q is of order q-1, and p divide q-1, so we can find the the homomorphism required for the semidirect product.

Comment: I am really doing lots of problems recently preparing for the exams, I did try for a long time, but I am not familiar with some definition and theorem, so I have not idea of what is going on, so any hint and even recommendation is help for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Let $Y$ be the cyclic group of order $q$ and $X$ be the cyclic group of order $p^2$, generated by $y$ and $x$ respectfully.  $|\text{Aut}(Y)|=q-1$, so because $p\mid q-1$ we have by Cauchy's that there is an element $\sigma\in \text{Aut}(Y)$ of order $p$.  (In particular, $x\mapsto x^a$, where $a$ is as described by the problem statement, is such an automorphism.)  Since $X$ is cyclic, it contains a normal subgroup of order $p$ (namely $\langle x^p \rangle$), and thus we can define a homomorphism $\lambda:X\rightarrow \text{Aut}(Y)$ so that $X/\text{ker}(\lambda)\cong \langle \sigma \rangle$.  Forming the semidirect product $G=Y\rtimes_\lambda X$ yields the desired group.

That answers part (a) and the first part of (b).  For the second part of (b), we have that $\text{ker}(\lambda)=\langle x^p \rangle$ acts trivially on $Y$, so $\langle y \rangle \times \langle x^p\rangle$ is the unique subgroup of order $pq$ in $G$ by construction.

Comment: I have a question, if $a^{p}\equiv 1 (mod q)$, then $y^{x^{p}}=1$, but I think it should be y

Comment: @user53800 Oh yes you're right, I was going too fast.  Let me fix that.

Comment: Ok,I appreciate for that. Thanks